# In scheduler How to active project in custom time

Tags: c#, console-application, scheduled-tasks, windows-console

Work on **C# VS2010** console application. My solution contains three projects. I set this solution exe on window schedule, Every morning scheduler active my solution projects consecutively , they work  perfectly ,but In every morning I want to active Project1 in 9AM, Project2 in 10AM, Project3 in 11AM,how to active them in different time when they all are in a solution .Is there any idea  how to active projects in custom time.

If  have any query plz ask ,thanks in advanced

Comment: What are you running in the scheduler, the EXE produced by building the solution? Are there 3 EXEs? What does the VS solution have to do with this? Are you building the solution as part of the scheduled task?

Comment: I was trying to edit this for clarity, but it turns out I don't completely understand the question. Bobbymcr asks a very important question here.

Comment: i get my answer ,thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 scheduled tasks, each one will pass a different parameter (the project to run) to the executable.

```
In the run textbox of each scheduled task :
    solution.exe 1
    solution.exe 2
    solution.exe 3

In your code :
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        switch(args[0]);
        {
            case "1":
                project1.run();
            ....
        }
    }
```